# How to show timezone in apache error logs

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, logging, configuration, log-files

How to show timezone in the apache 2.4.25 ErrorLog.
I have put the [ErrorLogFormat](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errorlogformat) in VirtualHost :

```
ErrorLogFormat "%{cu}t"
```

But than I only get `2018-02-08 10:02:59.246032`.
Which is the time in the +01:00 time in fact.

In [LogFormat](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html) it is possible just by `%{%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S}t.%{msec_frac}t%{%z}t` which gives `2018-02-08T10:07:46.161+0100`.
When I use the same in ErrorLogFormat I get `Thu Feb 08 10:07:46 2018.2018-02-08 10:07:46Thu Feb 08 10:07:46 2018` instead.

Is there a way to show the correct timezone?

Comment: you can see this my Dear good luck [enter link description here](https://serverfault.com/questions/26248/what-could-cause-apaches-time-timezone-to-change-intermittently)

Comment: you could of course put the timezone as static text in the format.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it is not possible. With [LogFormat](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat) it passes the format to `strftime(3)`, but with [ErrorLogFormat](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errorlogformat) it does not.

If the timezone is important to your ErrorLog, you can consider to use Logstash / ELK-stack for parsing the logs and adding a timestamp to the log entry before it is indexed.

Comment: I plan to log the all the Errors as JSON, and than use [filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/index.html) to send them out to redis db. Any idea how to process it such way with filebeat?

Comment: Found a way to add a timezone to beat using [processors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/add-locale.html), but still the timezone can be wrong when using reading old files after the timezone change. So to have it always correct it should be done on the writing of the logs, not reading

Answer (score 0):

The capability to get strftime in ErrorLogFormat is now available in the Apache HTTPD trunk branch in version 2.5.1:
https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/CHANGES

Look for PR 62161